# Use of array from a Foreach in multiple occasions

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having an issue when trying to present some information coming from an array.

I have a `foreach` that checks the `n` sessions in my site, then I call the database for each session and load an array of items.

After coming out of the `foreach`, I would like to use the same array sequentially to show the items one by one again, however I am only seeing the last of the items `n` times.

Essentially, in the second `foreach`, the `$row2['name']` and `$row2['price']` are only showing `n` number of times but always the last item of the table.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) 
{ 
$pid = $item['itemId'];
$q = $item['qty'];
if($q==0) continue;
$query2 = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE id_item = :idItem");
$query2-> bindValue (':idItem',$pid);
$query2->execute();
$row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
SOME HTML STUFF....
}
```

SOME INDEPENDENT HTML STUFF HERE:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)    
{
   $pid = $item['itemId'];
   $q = $item['qty'];
HTML <div class="subTotalItem">
   <span class='cartItemsText'><?php echo **$row2['name']**; ?></span>
<span class='cartItemsText2'><?php echo $q." x "." $".$**row2['price'];** $subTotal+= $row2['price'] * $q; ?></span>
    </div>
}
```

Any idea of where the issue might be?

Comment: After the first foreach completes, $row2 will contain the row retrieved from the last query.  You need to either run the queries again or consolidate your foreach loops into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your "stuff to display later" in a string and echo it where you need.

```
$subtotalStuff = "";

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) { 
    $pid = $item['itemId'];
    $q = $item['qty'];
    if($q==0) continue;

    $query2 = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE id_item = :idItem");
    $query2-> bindValue (':idItem',$pid);
    $query2->execute();
    $row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $subtotalStuff .= "<div class='subTotalItem'><span>" . $row2['name'] . "</span><span>" . $q . " x " . " $" . row2['price'] . "</span></div>\r\n";
    $subTotal+= $row2['price'] * $q;

    SOME HTML STUFF....
}

echo $subtotalStuff;
echo $subTotal;
```

Comment: $subtotalStuff is something that should be displayed n times with a foreach, that's why there should be 2 foreach

Comment: $subtotalStuff is a concatenation of all `n` rows, so you dont need 2 foreach

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the default option for prepared statements with PDO configured as PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY? If I'm right, that means you'd have to run the same query again to compose the HTML part of your code.

I have no experience with reversible cursors, but there's an option for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume you are somehow SETTING the $_SESSION['cart'] variable somewhere in your omitted "SOME HTML STUFF" section.  I say this because looking at your code, I would expect $_SESSION['cart'] to have the same exact values for the second foreach as it did for the first foreach.

Answer (score 0):

You should print out in the same loop as the query, $row2 is reset every time it goes through the loop.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) 
{ 
 $pid = $item['itemId'];
$q = $item['qty'];
if($q==0) continue;
$query2 = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE id_item = :idItem");
$query2-> bindValue (':idItem',$pid);
$query2->execute();
$row2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

SOME HTML STUFF....


Put your HTML output here, not in second loop

 }
```

This should work

Comment: It's 2 separate HTML areas of the page, I need to separate the foreaches since otherwise my html would not print correctly